# Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, transacciones

Estoy intentando usar transacciones en mi aplicacion PHP pero me sale el error:
 **Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction in x**

La estructura de mi aplicación es la siguiente:

**db.php**
En este archivo realizo la conexion de la siguente manera:

```
Class conexion{

    public static function Conectar(){

        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
        );

        try{
            $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname","user", "", $options);
            return $link;
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error : " . $e->getMessage(); 
        }

        return $link;

    }
}
```

y en mi archivo de consultas:

```
require_once "db.php";

    class Registro{

        public static function guardarRegistro($datosModel, $tabla){

            Conexion::conectar()->beginTransaction();

            try {

                $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO table_0 (data1, data2) VALUES  (:data1 ,:data2)");

                $stmt -> bindParam(":data1", "HOLA", PDO::PARAM_STR);   
                $stmt -> bindParam(":data2", "MUNDO", PDO::PARAM_STR);  
                $stmt->execute();

                // Obtener el ultimo registro...
                $ultimoID = Conexion::conectar()->lastInsertId();


                $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO table_1(FK_id, `status`) VALUES  (:id, 'ALTA')");
                $stmt -> bindParam(":id",   $ultimoID, PDO::PARAM_INT);             
                $stmt->execute();

                $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO table_2(FK_id, `status`) VALUES  (:id, 'ATENCION')");
                $stmt -> bindParam(":id",   $ultimoID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();

                Conexion::conectar()->commit();

            }catch (PDOException $e) {

                Conexion::conectar()->rollBack();

                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }
    }
```

y siempre me genera el error:  **Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction in x**

Especificando que es en esta linea donde tengo el error: `Conexion::conectar()->rollBack();`

Cabe destacar que hago un var_dump de mi variable **$ultimoID** y hasta esa parte si va bien.

He googleado y he encontrado algunas sugerencias a las que he aplicado pero no me  termina de funcionar mi código, agradezco cualquier observación que me pueda solucionar esta problemática

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que estás llamando al método que conecta a la base de datos ¡7 veces!. Eso hace que cada objeto sea distinto y no se reconozca el uno al otro. La llamada a `lastInsertId()` funciona porque desde cualquier conexión que lo invoques te mostraría el último ID insertado.

Crea un sólo objeto de conexión y luego usa ese objeto en todo.

Por ejemplo:

```
    public static function guardarRegistro($datosModel, $tabla){

        $pdo=Conexion::conectar(); #No necesitas conectar más, usa $pdo
        $pdo->beginTransaction();

        try {

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table_0 (data1, data2) VALUES  (:data1 ,:data2)");

            $stmt -> bindParam(":data1", "HOLA", PDO::PARAM_STR);   
            $stmt -> bindParam(":data2", "MUNDO", PDO::PARAM_STR);  
            $stmt->execute();

            // Obtener el ultimo registro...
            $ultimoID = $pdo->lastInsertId();


            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table_1(FK_id, `status`) VALUES  (:id, 'ALTA')");
            $stmt -> bindParam(":id",   $ultimoID, PDO::PARAM_INT);             
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table_2(FK_id, `status`) VALUES  (:id, 'ATENCION')");
            $stmt -> bindParam(":id",   $ultimoID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            $pdo->commit();

        }catch (PDOException $e) {

            $pdo->rollBack();

            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```